# Why is there no plural indefinite article?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, articles, indefinite-articles

*The* takes either a singular or a plural subject.  *A/an* only takes the singular.

When we pluralize a noun preceded by an indefinite article, we simply drop the article (sometimes replacing it with *some*).  Why is this?

---

**3 years later:**

Whilst on [a separate goose-chase](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/192954/10041), I came across Greg Carlson's 1977 paper [A Unified Analysis of the English Bare Plural](http://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/classes/f11/na/docs/carlson77.pdf), which addresses this issue in refreshing detail. It does not answer my question etymologically, but it substantiates the premise that the so-called null determiner is ambiguous:

> ABSTRACT. It is argued that the English ‘bare plural’ (an NP with plural head that lacks a 
>   determiner), in spite of its apparently diverse possibilities of interpretation, is optimally represented in the grammar as a unified phenomenon. The chief distinction to be dealt with is that between the ‘generic’ use of the bare plural (as in ‘*Dogs* bark’) and its existential or ‘indefinite plural’ use (as in ‘He threw *oranges* at Alice’). ‘Ihe difference between these uses is not to be accounted for by an ambiguity in the NP itself, but rather by explicating how the context of the sentence acts on the bare plural to give rise to this distinction. A brief analysis is sketched in which bare plurals are treated in all instances as proper names of kinds of things. A subsidiary argument is that the null determiner is not to be regarded as the plural of the indefinite article *a*.

The primary distinction is summed up in these examples:

*Weeds grow* refers to **all** weeds, or weeds in general. It is not equivalent to *Some weeds grow*.

*Weeds grow in my garden* refers to some weeds, and is equivalent to *Some weeds grow in my garden*.

I understand that context is often sufficient to determine the scope of the noun without a plural indefinite article<sup>1</sup> - but that applies to the singular indefinite article *a/an* as well. In fact, it seems that *a/an* is even more redundant, since both *Dog barks* and *Dog barks in my garden* are equally indefinite, not generic.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Carlson 2001](http://www.ling.rochester.edu/people/faculty/carlson_greg/assets/pdf/generics/Determination.pdf) is further germane analysis. In here, he gives examples of sentences for which context is not sufficient to determine the scope of the null determiner. For instance, *I only excluded old ladies* can mean I excluded *all* old ladies (generic), or that all those whom I excluded happen to have been old ladies (indefinite - some old ladies may have gotten in after all).

Comment: How are we supposed to answer why something _isn't_?

Comment: @MrHen: Colin Fine says Maori has a plural indefinite article, so it's not like the concept is meaningless. And the fact that we call *the/a/an* the *definite/indefinite articles* suggests they have much in common. In which case it's potentially enlightening to examine things they *don't* have in common, such as the ability to take a plural subject.

Comment: @Alain: You must undelete your answer! It was excellent: I was going to answer something like that. P.S. The Greeks did have articles, just no indefinite ones.

Comment: @MrHen: There can be reasons why, contrary to what one might expect, a certain feature never developed. In this case, Alain's deleted answer explain it it very nicely and informatively, I should think.

Comment: As far as I know, most Latin-derived languages have separate singular and plural definite and indefinite articles. It's a common feature in (some) indoeuropean languages.

Comment: @Cerberus, My answer was deleted because I did not have time to finish it. I'm back in a hotel with poor Internet connectivity - painful. However, you're right about the Greek definite articles. How much time did I spend repeating "ὁ, τόν, τοῦ, τῷ" at school.

Comment: @Alain: I learned "ὁ, τοῦ, τῷ, τόν"; NGDA.  Isn't that how it usually is?

Comment: @drm65. I learned Ancient Greek mainly in France and briefly when I was a pupil in Sevenoaks Kent.  In France, the cases order in which the declensions are taught is "Nom [voc], Acc, Gen, Dat [abl]".  I know it's different in the UK and the US. Plus we pronounce "th" as /t/.

Comment: OK.  The only difference I see is that Acc is after Voc instead of Dat.  Interesting.

Comment: N.B. In considering this, be careful not to conflate two different situations, one where a bare nominal is possible, and one where a quantifier such as "some" is used. For example, consider: "(Some) children were playing on the swings; they were called Daniel and Peter". Depending on whether or not you insert the word "some" determines whether it sounds odd to include the second part of the sentence. So "indefinite" and "indeterminate" aren't necessarily the same thing.

Comment: This question has been repeated on https://redd.it/52nm5e

Comment: I read some books on the table. 'some' refers to plurality, but also 'individuality'. I did not know how many, but I can identify the books I read. What is the staus of 'some'?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In most languages indefinite articles stem from that language's word for *one*.  For instance in French *un*, or in German *ein*, In Italian and Spanish *uno* or in Portuguese *um*.

English is no exception: ***an*** was derived from *one*.  Note that ***an*** was the original indefinite article; the shorter  ***a*** came later when the final "n" was dropped before consonants.

In some of the languages I mentioned above, the plural form of the indefinite articles is simply formed by applying the noun plural inflection: *unos/unas* or *uns/umas*.

In others, such as German and Italian, there is no plural form to the indefinite article.  Italian use the partitive article *degli/delle* as a substitute and this is probably also the origin of the French plural form *des*.

For some reason English did not go through this last step either.  To understand why we need to go back to the way Old English solved the problem.

In Old English adjectives have a different declension depending on whether the noun they qualify is determined or not.

"*The* glad man" reads

> se glæd guma

whereas, "*a* happy man" is:

> glæda guma

As one can see, only the adjective changes.
For one given adjective, you could therefore have different inflections depending on:
 - the noun gender (masculine, feminine, neuter)
 - the noun being singular or plural
 - the four cases (nominative, accusative, genitive, dative)
 - whether the reference is definite or indefinite.
So that the same adjective would have to follow either the "definite" declension or one of three "indefinite" declensions.

> þa glædan guman

**Edit**
**<conjecture>**
The theory I'm trying to check (community please feel free to edit) is that in various languages (Icelandic for a language very close to Old English or Romanian) the article is added as a suffix to the noun.  Then it often "detaches" and passes *in front* of the noun.  Icelandic is half way through for the definite article in that matter.

As for the Old English indefinite article, my conjecture is that the process never went through for a number of possible reasons:
 - The "loss of inflection" of early Middle English won the race
 - The plural of "an" was not easy to evolve at that time (the Romance "-s" plural had not imposed itself yet).
**</conjecture>**

But the need is still there, just as in any other language where a specific word emerged for the plural indefinite article.  This gap is filled by placeholders such as ***some*** or ***a number of***.

Most linguist agree that Proto Indo European did not use articles. 
Latin does not have any kind of article, and Ancient Greek arguably had no indefinite article either - it was using something very much like present-day English **some** (τις - "a certain"). And I believe that Old German did not have any article either.

It is a very remarkable fact that articles appeared in many modern Indo European languages in a largely mutually independent yet very similar manner.  My feeling is that their emergence compensates for the gradual loss of inflection in these languages.  But then present-day German is a powerful counterexample...

Comment: I don't believe that German has a plural form of indefinite articles (*einem* is dative singular), but Spanish and Catalan (two languages I don't know) apparently do.

Comment: @PeterShor, Thanks. I corrected. Actually Italian doesn't have any plural article either.  As for German I'll be tempted to use "einige" (which is also present in Old English (ænig) and actually evolved into "any").  Thx community ;-)

Comment: @Peter Shor: Indeed, Spanish, Catalan and Galician do have plural indefinite articles.

Comment: Yay! Excellent. // Your theory that articles developed to compensate for loss of inflection may be true for the indefinite article; for definite articles, it may still be true, but Greek weakens it a bit (elaborate inflection but plentiful definite articles). // As to your theory about articles having originally been suffixes: surely that applies only to those few languages you mentioned? // German has three types of adject. inflection, roughly 1. after definite article, 2. after indefinite article, 3. without article. Dutch has 1. definite, 2. indefinite/without. Greek had no different types.

Comment: @Cerberus.  From what I've seen the weak adjectives inflection for definite nouns is a Germanic innovation that can be observed in many present and ancient languages - with variations (Old English, German, Swedish, Danish, Icelandic etc).  In many cases the definite article is enclitic and sometimes doubles with a separate *proclitic* demonstrative.  My feeling is that if this complex inflectional system disappears ("weakens" ;-), then the proclitic demonstrative becomes more frequent/necessary, possibly influenced by the enclitic article.  In short it "passes in front".[...]

Comment: [...] The case of Romanian is special because it probably acquired its enclitic article from the neighbouring Slavic languages.  As for the indefinite article, although Greek and German are powerful counterexamples, I'm still inclined to "guess" a similar mechanism where "one/ein/un/uno" is becoming more necessary as inflectional complexity gradually fades away. I know this is just the possibly completely off the mark feeling of a dilettante but, I'll try to confirm/infirm this theory - time permitting.

Comment: French does have an indefinite plural article: “des”

Comment: @Konrad. Thx. Corrected. I initially meant to say it was a partitive article turned full fledged indefinite article.

Comment: Spanish has plural indefinite articles: *unos*, *unas*.  These tend to be replaced by things like *algunos/-as*.

Answer (score 11):

As pointed out elsewhere, language is the result of an evolutionary process, not logical design.

The origins of the word "the" aren't connected with those of "a/an", so there's no reason why they should share all characteristics.

As OP says, "some" can function as a kind of 'plural' for "a/an". So can "a few", "a number of", etc. In some contexts, "any" can be used as the pluralised version of "a/an". I'm not overly concerned about the scope of the term "indefinite article" – it's just a (sometimes enlightening) name we often use, not a 'pre-existing' class into which any given word either falls or doesn't.

It's not as if our language is seriously restricted by not allowing for "a/an" to be used of multiple subjects. And after all, in some contexts "a" can effectively refer to multiple subjects where "the" implies a single one...

> "A president should be allowed to say he 'screwed up', surely?"
>
> "I'm not talking about *a* president, *the* president shouldn't have said that!"

**LATER**: More specifically addressing OP's question as to *why* "a/an" can't be pluralised the same as "the". Firstly, note that in the above example, "a" *is effectively pluralised* – as becomes clear when you realise it means "presidents in general" rather than "a randomly selected president".

Secondly, consider "Recipe: Mix some cloves, a cinnamon stick, and apples in a bowl". There's *no need for an article* when we pluralise "an apple" there.

Thirdly, as @Robusto implies, some/many/most/all contexts where you would use the indefinite article in reference to "one of it" simply don't lead to meaningful contexts if there is more than one of it.

Fourthly, "a" *can mean exactly "one"*, particularly in contexts associated with 'countability' (so can "the", but more in the context of 'identification'). This makes us leery of using it around plural subjects, because we sense it sits uneasily with 'one-ness' of "a".

Comment: So it's just the randomness in language formation?  There's no logical reason for it?

Comment: Umm. One of the forces affecting language change is in fact logic - in various ways including the bias towards adopting forms that seem to correspond to our logical view of the world, and discarding those that don't. Which is why English, for example, has managed to ditch a lot of the 'sexual gender' distinctions made irrelevantly in lots of other languages.

Comment: So would you say that we should introduce a plural indefinite article, to be more logical?

Comment: Nowhere near as much as I would say we should introduce a gender-neutral personal pronoun to substitute for *his/hers*, and that ain't gonna happen any time soon. I didn't say it's overridingly important that language be logical; just that logical considerations do affect its evolution sometimes. I'm mainly a descriptivist, not a prescriptivist.

Comment: I agree.  I was just confused by your first comment above.

Comment: Somewhat conveniently, you fail to mention that we get along just fine without a plural indefinite article.

Comment: @Robusto: I also somewhat conveniently forgot to address OP's second question: *"why is 'some' not considered to be an indefinite article?"*, because I wouldn't mind considering it as such. I just don't want to argue about that with others who might say I was wrong.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I agree 100% with the start of your answer but then less and less with the rest of it the further down the page I read.

Comment: @hippietrail: Well don't just leave me hanging! Where did I drift off-course? Bear in mind the Q is *"why doesn't 'a/an' pluralise the way 'the' does?"*. I don't think you can answer that by saying *Because it doesn't*, or *because we don't need it to* (even though I might like to! :)

Comment: @Fumble: I'm still reading and honing my knowledge and opinion. I'll try to replace this comment with something more helpful if I don't get too distracted. Sorry (-:

Comment: +1 since you bumped the question :P  No really, I must have somehow forgotten to upvote this!

Comment: @drɱ65: I really did look for an edit to bump the question (not my answer, honest!), because I followed your link on the other one and was reminded that this is still an excellent question itself, *and* relevant to the other one. I like Alain's answer here too - but his is more about the history, mine is more about how we get by perfectly well with the reduced number of articles we decided to keep.

Answer (score 6):

When you are referring to a specific item or specific items, you use "the", like

> I have the steak.

or

> I have the steaks.

When you are referring to a "nonspecific" item, you use "a" for the singular, like

> I have a steak.

If you were to leave out "a", you would get

> I have steak.

How many steaks do you have?  One massive steak? Two steaks? Exactly π steaks? 4/5 of a steak?  Without the article, "steak" in this example becomes a "non-counted" entity; you aren't indicating anything about whether there are discrete items.  In

> I have a steak.

you are referring to a collection of discrete items.  When you say

> I have steaks.

though, it is clear that you are referring to discrete items.  If "steaks" is plural, you have to be able to count them and therefore have to have more than one *discrete* item.  The article isn't necessary.  However, you can say

> I have some steaks.

According to the Wikipedia entry for "[article (grammar)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29)", "The articles in the English language are the and a/an, and (in some contexts) *some*." (emphasis added)  In the case of talking about "indefinite objects", the article isn't needed to show that you are talking about discrete items or specific items.

Comment: This in no wise answers the question, except for your last paragraph, which quotes an entirely unreferenced opinion in Wikipedia. (I'm not saying it is wrong, just that Wikipedia is reliable only where it is referenced). I'm sure @drm65 knows all you are saying, but is asking Why? My answer is with FumbleFingers: because it doesn't. It is probably not a coincidence that AFAIK no European language has a plural indefinite article: Maori is an example of a language which has.

Comment: @Colin: In a number of different European languages (English, German, French, Hungarian), the indefinite article comes from the word for 1, which explains why it doesn't pluralize. It doesn't seem likely to me that this simultaneous evolution could have been a coincidence, although it is indeed remarkably natural.

Comment: @Colin: [Catalan](http://mylanguages.org/catalan_articles.php) seems to be a European language with indefinite articles in the plural, and also one which gives a counterexample to my previous comment.

Comment: @Peter Shor: As I said somewhere else, you don't need to look at Catalan (which is a correct example); Spanish has indefinite articles in the plural as well and is likely to be better known here.

Comment: @compman: I think you mean "discrete"

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Old English [did not have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English_declension#Determiners) any indefinite articles. And [from Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_%28grammar%29#Indefinite_article)

> English uses a/an, from the Old English forms of the number 'one', as
>   its primary indefinite article.

If *a/an* was derived from *an,* which was derived from the number *one,* there logically wouldn't be any corresponding derivation of a plural indefinite article. So modern English doesn't have one.

Comment: The Old English form of the modern English "this guy" meaning "a guy" as in "So, this guy walks into a bar..." was "sum man", and "sum" was declined as an adjective.

Comment: By "form" I should better have written "counterpart".

Comment: The Spanish plural *unos/unas* suggests that an English plural like *?ones/ans* or (if it is an adjective and so did not decline) *one/an/a* might not be logically impossible

Answer (score 2):

> I realize that *some* is an effective substitute for plural *a*, but in that case, why is it not considered to be an indefinite article?

Because in English the indefinite articles are *an* and *a*; *some*, *a*, *an*, *the*, and [other words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_%28linguistics%29#English_determiners_2) are classified as determiners.
It just a matter of classification; for example, the NOAD copy that comes with Mac OS X 10.6 ("New Oxford American Dictionary 2nd edition © 2005 by Oxford University Press, Inc.") classifies *a* and *the* as adjectives.

> a /eɪ/ (*an* before a vowel sound) [called the indefinite article]
>   adjective
>   1. used when referring to someone or something for the first time in a text or conversation: "a man came out of the room"; "it has been an honor to have you"; "we need people with a knowledge of languages."

> the /ði/ /ð(ə)/ /ði/ [called the definite article]
>   adjective
>   1. denoting one or more people or things already mentioned or assumed to be common knowledge: "what's the matter?"; "call the doctor"; "the phone rang."

The NOAD that comes with the Mac OS X 10.7 ("New Oxford American Dictionary 3rd edition © 2010 by Oxford University Press, Inc.") defines the articles as determiners.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. --"Why aren't dogs considered to be reptiles?" --"Because reptiles are (insert exhaustive list of reptiles here)."  To answer the question, we need to establish definitions for "determiner" and "indefinite article", and establish why "a/an" meets the criteria for both, while "some" fails to meet the criteria for "indefinite article"

Comment: 'The' is not an adjective.  It is not a quality of the subject but a quality of the memory of the subject - that it was most recently activated.  It helps determine which to access.  Before a narrative is stored in the brain, 'the' has already been eliminated from the meme.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you don't need an article with plural nouns.

Singular:

> A unicorn is a mythical beast.

Plural:

> Unicorns are mythical beasts.

You would use definite plural pronouns if you want to refer to a specific group within a larger set.

> These unicorns are mythical. Those unicorns are real.

Comment: But if we didn't have any *singular* indefinite articles (as in some languages), we wouldn't need them, either. I'm not asking whether we need them; I'm asking why we have one and not the other.  Both are equally optional.

Comment: Just to cloud the issue a bit more, I see nothing wrong with saying *"The unicorn is a mythical beast"*. :)

Comment: @drm65: If we didn't have a use for them, we wouldn't have them. That's as much as you can say. A language has what it finds useful to have. Obviously, in English both are not needed, else we would have them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That is not germane to the issue. No one disputes that you can use the definite article to construct a similar sentence.

Comment: I didn't raise the possibility of interchanging "the" and "a" to refute anything said or implied. Just to suggest possible further complexity in that we might use "the" *instead of pluralised "a"*. Your reaction seems unduly curt and dismissive.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your quest started from the well-know but erroneous assumption that the core function of "a/an" is to determine a following noun as indefinite, as the name "indefinite article" suggests.

The core function of "a/an" is not to determine the following noun as indefinite but to determine the following noun as an individual entity. Only after "a/an" determines the following noun as an individual entity can the "indefinite" article determine the following noun as indefinite.

Therefore, the so-called "indefinite" article is automatically precluded from preceding *any* plural noun, because plural nouns cannot be determined as an individual entity.

Answer (score -1):

The plural indefinite is probably not in use because it would be superfluous given other more efficent ways of expressing the notion of indefinite.

> We use spoons to eat our soup in this land, though in other lands men drink straight from the bowl.
>
> We use [plural indefinite article] spoons to eat our soup in this land...
>
> We use a spoon to eat our soup, don't we, Johnny?

Comment: If this were relevant, why should we have a singular indefinite article? This is not an answer, but a restatement of the question.

Answer (score -2):

In English, we do not inflect adjectives by number. In particular, we do not inflect articles by number.  (Unlike French ... **l'haricot vert** and **les haricots verts**.)

Comment: True enough, but that doesn't have much to do with the question.  Adjectives, though not inflected by number, _are_ able to modify either singular or plural subjects.  The indefinite article is also not inflected by number, but unlike common adjectives it is _not_ able to modify plural subjects.  My question was: why not?

Comment: I wonder.  **A** with plural, collective... "A government have the right to do that."  Too strange.