# Why is 'more than one' considered singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“There is/are more than one”. What's the difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/there-is-are-more-than-one-whats-the-difference)

As a native English speaker I do some things naturally that I am unable to explain to foreigners. For example today I wrote this:

> There is always more than one factor to consider.

Raw instinct tells me that the singular verb **is** is correct, yet in the object there is specifically 'more than one' item. What grammar rule would you show people to explain that even though a plural concept is being refered to the word in that is being matched is specifically 'factor'?

I could have written this differently and used the plural verb **are**:

> There are always more factors than one to consider.

The only difference is word order and the fact that because 'factor' became 'factors' the verb had to change. Yet in both cases there was a plural concept as the object to the sentence.