# "There is X ways to..." vs "There are X ways to..."

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, there-is

I wrote an essay and returned it to my teacher who told me that it was perfect except for that one mistake with the usage of *there are*:

> *There are* currently 192 218 546 ways to set up..."

She marked it as incorrect. She told me that I should use "is" in lieu of "are".

As I am pretty sure that I have it the right way, I decided to ask the community here this question.  I find this community is the most accurate and by far the friendliest.

Comment: I'd have written "there are" just like you. Then again, I'm a non-native speaker.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You're correct. "*There are* currently (N>1) *ways* to set up..." is correct. "There *is* one way" and "there *is* no way"... (I am AmE.) Since you're here, please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
 and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help)
 for guidance on how to use this site. Again, welcome!

Comment: Your teacher does not know the rules of English grammar. If you had written _There's_, **that** would've been correct. But _There is_ is uncontracted and therefore should be pluralized to _There are_.

Comment: @medica is proving to be a great hostess for the site. Great.

Answer (score 3):

You were right originally — you use *are* when talking about a plural, and *ways* is clearly a plural.