# "Is" or "Are" Mickey and Minnie coming?

Tags: grammatical-number

"Is" or "Are" Mickey and Minnie coming?

Should I use is or are in this question? Thank you.

Comment: Ask yourself this: Is the subject "Mickey and Minnie" singular or plural?

Comment: "Are the Mouses coming?"

Answer (score 1):

Try and form a sentence first. You would say "Mickey and Minnie *are* coming," because there are more than one nouns.

Now you can go ahead and form a question from it, which would be "*Are* Mickey and Minnie coming?"

Comment: I did in fact want to add a comment. But I haven't yet gotten the 50 reputation points needed to comment. My apologies. // What would be the correct form of that?

Comment: Hello, sudhanva. As @Reg Dwight has said before now, '[W]e write stuff in comments that is too obvious to qualify for an answer. [This] is not really a topic for a site for linguists and etymologists, and we don't want it to become a topic.' Note that curious-proofreader used a 'comment' rather than an 'answer' here. // 'There are more than one nouns' may look logical but is ungrammatical. // I've corrected my typo, but you haven't corrected the ungrammaticality. // Assume that others can and will deal with so simple a question (preferably by close-voting). We've all been below 50.

Comment: I suppose I got a bit overzealous. I apologise again. // I was hoping you could tell me the proper grammar for 'there are more than one nouns' as I am not certain how to fix it. Thanks :)

Comment: [This was covered on ELU long ago.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/there-is-are-more-than-one-whats-the-difference)