# Is "series" plural or singular?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

The word `series` seems to generally refer to a group which I would think makes it a singular reference, however the `ies` ending is also a common way to modify a singular noun into a plural noun (eg., puppies, fancies, harpies).

So is `series` plural or singular, and if plural, what is the singular version?

Comment: It can be used either way, depending on what you want to draw attention to in the sentence: the whole as a unit, or the individual constituents. That will govern number agreement in other verbs, etc.

Comment: It's the same with ***species***. In a comment to a question I asked here some years ago, [I chose "**species**" in my example because it's the same form in singular and plural.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/there-is-are-more-than-one-whats-the-difference/108112#comment64317_35391)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

***[Series](https://www.etymonline.com/word/series#etymonline_v_23267)***  is singular and doesn’t  change in the plural. Its spelling originates from Latin:

> 1610s, ***"a number or set of things*** of one kind arranged in a line," from Latin series "row, chain, series, sequence, succession".

(Etymonline)

Comment: Series is plural and doesn't change in the singular.

Answer (score 11):

"Series" can be singular or plural depending on context.

> I like to watch TV series.

Uses series as a plural and means you like to watch a number of different TV shows.

> I like to watch a TV series.

Uses series as singular and means you like to watch one TV show.