# Origin of distinction between "one" and "a/an"?

Tags: etymology, numbers, indefinite-articles

So I was told that the English articles "a" and "an" have Germanic origins. In German, there is not a distinction between "one" and "a/an". Is there any explanation for the existence of these two different words in English? Is there a situation in which "one" and "a/an" cannot be interchanged? I suspect that "a/an" is just easier to say....but maybe I am just biased to think so, as I am a native English speaker.

Comment: I thought in German you have both? Like, eine pizza and die pizza, or something like that?

Comment: Welcome, SWV but this too big and too general a question to be answered in a paragraph or two here. The Oxford English Dictionary has 745 words on the topic. To understand why we use 'a'/'an' you first have to understand the difference between definite and indefinite. You should be able to find information on that readily enough elsewhere. A moment's reflection will show that there are many situations where 'one' and 'a'/'an' are not interchangeable. Would you say 'I'd like one lot of money' if you meant 'I'd like a lot of money'?

Comment: @RiMMERΨ: I may be wrong, but I think you are comparing the German equivalents of "a/an" and "the."

Comment: @RiMMERΨ Ψ: In German, 'eine Pizza' is indefinite, 'die Pizza, definite. But SWV is right in saying that 'ein' (with its other inflected forms) means 'one' as well as 'a'.

Comment: @BarrieEngland: I don't really see the difference between "one lot" and "a lot." Presumably, one seems more specific than the other; however, I interpret both to be equally vague, as it is the word "lot" the carries quantitative ambiguity.

Comment: @SWV: OK, then would you say 'I have one few things to say to you' if you meant 'I have a few things to say to you'?

Comment: To quote Lawrence Welk:"A one an a two"

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35378/why-is-there-no-plural-indefinite-article

Comment: Related: [Are there languages with indefinite articles but for which the word for “one” is not related etymologically to any of the indefinite articles?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/641/are-there-languages-with-indefinite-articles-but-for-which-the-word-for-one-is)

Answer (score 2):

**A/an** isn't used when counting. What's more, in narrations, we say *one day, one afternoon,* **one** cannot be replaced by **a/an** in these expressions.

It's true that in other languages the indefinite article isn't different from the word denoting the number 1. In [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/an) it is stated that the differentiation came about through the pronunciation of the word **one** without stress (I suppose when not counting).